# MongoDb query taking a long time

Tags: mongodb, optimization, indexing

I have a collection of vectors
The size of the collection

```
print vectors.count()
```

is

> > 102020

When I iterate through the fields

```
start = time.time()
for v in vectors.find({},{'vector' : 1, '_id' : 0}):
    pass
print "total time:" , end-start
```

> > total time: 5.05100011826

but when I run with explain() I see that the query takes substantially less time.

```
print vectors.find({},{'vector' : 1, '_id' : 0}).explain()
```

> > {u'nYields': 0, u'allPlans': [{u'cursor': u'BasicCursor', u'indexBounds': {}}], u'nChunkSkips': 0, u'**millis': 23**, u'n': 102020, u'cursor': u'BasicCursor', u'indexBounds': {}, u'nscannedObjects': 102020, u'isMultiKey': False, u'indexOnly': False, u'nscanned': 102020}

Why is there such a huge time difference? Is there anyway to speed this up?
I loaded all of the vectors to a sql DB text field and the same query was less than one second.
Thanks

Comment: Isn't time.time() in ms .. so the normal query is taking 5ms and 23ms with the explain?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the second one merely shows you how fast it takes for mongoDB to actually execute 'find' while the former also involves retrieving every single record to the console, and processing them.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to play with [batch_size](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.batch_size) to improve the speed and reduce the amount of network hops when iterating through results.

```
start = time.time()
for v in vectors.find({},{'vector' : 1, '_id' : 0}).batch_size(1000):
    pass
print "total time:" , end-start
```

Comment: I tried that and even when doing batch size larger than my record set I had horrible performance.

Comment: Is it possible to load the whole DB to memory?

Comment: The data is all in virtual memory, so by touching the files you could get all the data into ram.  It might just be the cost of transmitting the data and then iterating it.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an index to the field you want to query,in your case it is `"vector"` i.e:

```
vectors.createIndex({"vector":1},{sparse:true})
```

then you can check the time for query.